# What is the earliest instance of magic smelling like ozone?

Tags: history-of, magic, powers

Aside from being set in pretty cynical universes, both Andrzej Sapkowski's *Witcher* saga and Sandy Mitchell's *Ciaphas Cain* stories don't have a lot in common, aside from one thing that's nearly identical:...

> My mouth went dry, and on the back of my tongue I could suddenly taste the **ozone** crackle of **sorcery**.
> (Sandy Mitchell, *Duty Calls*, Chapter Ten)

...magic smells like ozone in both.
Which is a detail I recall seeing *numerous* times in many different books, webcomics, and video games.

And yet, it is such a tiny detail that even finding confirmation for my two examples seems nearly impossible. And any other examples remain frustratingly on the tip of my tongue. So maybe if I know who came up with this idea *first* will ease up my sense of deja vu.

**What is the earliest instance of magic** (or psionics, or technosorcery, or the Force, or whatever local equivalent) **smelling like ozone?**

Comment: Would a magical *creature* count?  The fireworm Eldest in Diane Duane's *So You Want to Be a Wizard* is accompanied by an overpowering smell of ozone.

Comment: I feel like this may have shown up in one or two Zelazny stories (maybe when Amberites walked the Pattern?).

Comment: Person voting to close should give a reason. Seems like a cromulent "first instance" question, of which there are plenty on SFF.SE.

Comment: @DavidW Honestly, I'm not sure. On the one hand, **probably not**, because I'm asking about the smell of ozone *inherently* being tied to magic. On the other hand, **probably yes**, if the book is *explicit* that this magical creature smells like ozone *"as all magical things do"* (as opposed to the situation where, say, fireworms specifically smell like ozone, while watercats, earthbirds, and airlephants are O3-free; or fireworms are the only "magical" creatures and it's unclear whether they smell like that because of magic or because they're cleanliness freaks).